# Asterisk as a SIP client dynamic configuration

Tags: configuration, asterisk, sip

I am moving from asterisk 1.x to 13.6.In current implementation to dynamically register/unregister asterisk as different sip clients I use following trick: In sip.conf file I include my custom conf file which I update(add/remove) with "register =>..." and then "sip reload". 
***Do we have better way to do this in new asterisk version?***

As variant I would like to include in sip.conf not single file but several from specific folder. ***Is it possible in asterisk config files?***

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Asides from using realtime (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration) and sorcery (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Sorcery+Caching), you can use "exec".

I'm not sure this is the desired way to do this, but you can take advantage of the "exec" include, see: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+The+include,+tryinclude+and+exec+Constructs

So Asterisk would execute a script of yours (shell, php, ruby, etc) that will output everything you need, and there's no need to add multiple "include" statements.

For this to work you should have in your asterisk.conf:

```
execincludes = yes
```

Not performant, not pretty, might have some security issues if you are not careful, but could do the job if you don't want to use any realtime or sorcery configuration.